# NodeJS as Websocket client using ws

Tags: node.js, websocket

I need to send a message to a websocket server through request POST. The client is not a browser but a Node server.

I'm new to websocket.

When I run the code below.

```
var WebSocket = require("ws");
const express = require("express");
var app = express();

const client = new WebSocket(process.env.URL);
client.on("error", handleError);

client.onopen = () => {
  client.send("Message From Client");
};

function handleError(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

app.get("/echo", async function (req, res) {
  client.once("connection", function connection(cli) {
    cli.send(msg);
    res.send("send");
  });
});

app.listen(3333, function () {
  console.log("Example app listening on port 3333!");
});
```

It shows the error

```
Error: write EPROTO 19524:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:16) {
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with express, but it should be similar to https. Here is how to do it with https.

Basically it has to be the `https server` that should listen on certain port and also have certs and keys as option passed to it. Then you would pass the `https server` to `websocket server`.

When client connects, it'll connect to https and then upgrade to WSS.

Which means your client application can connect to `wss://test.mysite.com:1234`.

```
const https = require('https')   

const options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/test.mysite.com/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/test.mysite.com/privkey.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/test.mysite.com/chain.pem')
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(options);

httpsServer.listen(1234, () => console.log('Https Server running on port 1234'));

var ws = new WebSocket.Server({
  server: httpsServer
});

ws.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Conencted')
});
```